# Apache VirtualHost DocumentRoot to another server

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, proxmox

I run two webservers, each in their own VM under Proxmox.

Incoming web traffic goes to one of these. That one has a .conf file with various `<VirtualHost>` entries to send traffic to the correct locations for sites on that server (/var/www/xyx etc).

But I want one of those entries have a DocumentRoot directive to point to a different server on the same Proxmox machine.

I've tried variations of these entries, but they didn't work:

```
   DocumentRoot http://192.168.01.022
   DocumentRoot "http://192.168.01.022"
   DocumentRoot 192.168.37.222
```

I then went down a rabbit hole talking about ProxyPass etc so I tried many variations of:

```
   ProxyPreserveHost on
   ProxyPass        / http://192.168.37.222
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.37.222
```

Nothing seemed to work, the best I got was an "403 Forbidden, You don't have permission to access this resource" error. (Each VM can open a website on the other but maybe that's because I am root user?)

So two questions:

1. what is the correct syntax to use in the `<VirtualHost>` entry?
2. If I get the redirect to work, how do I get the correct permissions passed through?

As said above, I've tried using VirtualHosts and Proxy servers, I haven't looked at redirects

Comment: Unclear.  The title says "on another server", later it says "another server on the same machine".  Assuming you have to separate Apache instances, that are not hosted on the same OS, you can do: **1** domain abc.com on apache 1 redirects to cde.com on the second.  So you use the domain to split traffic.  **2** point each domain to a different external IP, so you can control which external IP goes to which Apache (preferred solution as each instance is indenpendant. **3** setup a proxy from apache1 to apache2.  You must explain better to provide more detailed suggestions.

Comment: Worst case, setup an NFS between systems?  That can be slow, not recommended.  Or setup a shared filesystem.  Again, overkill IMHO.

Comment: Solved: I've installed nginx as a reverse proxy and this directs traffic to the correct VM. Thanks for your suggestions Nic3500. Just for clarification, there are two servers, each running in their own VM on the same machine (which runs Proxmox).